# Controls at the bottom of UIScrollView not working

Tags: swift

The UIButton in the scrollView is visible, but not accessible. I am using Constraints.

My UI structure is this: 
`- UIView
   - scrollView: UIScrollView
     - contentView: UIView
       - UIButton
       - UIButton
       - UIButton
       - ....
       - UIButton`

I've already tried to set the contentSize of the scrollView. And the height of the contentView. Next to that I've tried to uncheck the checkbox Adjust Scroll View Insets in the storyboard of that ViewController without any luck. I've also set the priority of the Align Center Y to 250, and the priority bottom space to 250 of the contentView.

```
func updateScrollViewSize() {
    var contentRect = CGRect.zero
    for view in contentView.subviews {
        contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
    }

    contentRect.size = CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: contentRect.height + 50)
    scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
    contentView.frame.size = contentRect.size
    contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The button I try to reach has a Y value of: 1030.0 
The height of the contentView is: 871.0

Comment: Use auto-layout and constraints... absolutely no need to be trying to calculate rect sizes and contentSize.

Comment: I'm using auto-layout and constraints. Without the updateScrollViewSize() function the values are still the same as described in the question

Comment: Then you have them setup incorrectly. Start small... add a scroll view to your view... add a "content view" to your scroll view... add a button to that content view. See if you can set the constraints properly so you can tap the button. Then start adding additional UI elements, one-at-a-time, changing the constraints so you don't loose the ability to tap the button. ***DO NOT*** write any code dealing with the scrollView's `.contentSize`.

Comment: Without this line of code: `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentView.frame.width, height: 1000)` the scrollview won't scroll all the way down. The controls are accessible until the point where you have to scroll to access a control

Comment: If the scrollView *"won't scroll all the way down"* then you have your constraints wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step-by-step:

Add a scroll view to your view, background color red, constrain it 20-pts on each side:

[image]

Add a `UIView` as your "content view" to the scroll view (green background to make it easy to see), constrain it 0-pts on each side, constrain equal width and equal height to the scroll view. **Important**: change the Priority of the Height constraint to `250`!

[image]

Add a `UILabel` to the contentView, constrain it 30-pts from the top, centered horizontally:

[image]

Add another label to the contentView, constrain it 300-pts from the first label, centered horizontally:

[image]

Add a `UIButton` to the contentView, constrain it 30-pts from the **bottom**, centered horizontally:

[image]

Now add a vertical constraint from the bottom of the second label to the top of the button, and set it to 400-pts:

[image]

As you see, this pushes the button off-screen past the bottom of the scroll view.

Run the app. You will be able to scroll down to see the button, and you'll be able to tap it.

Absolutely no code needed!

Answer (score 0):

If you use AutoLayout, you don't needed to install frames manually.

You can try install constraints properly and content size will be right in this case and you won't have to install content size manually.

If you achieve this, I guess everything will work correctly.

You can follow [this](https://medium.com/@luisfmachado/uiscrollview-autolayout-on-a-storyboard-a-step-by-step-guide-15bd67ee79e9) or [this](https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7) guide